# One-handed mode for windows 8.1 (Nokia Lumia 1520)

Tags: 8.1, lumia

There are features that help to operate a large phone with one hand like reachability for iOS or one-handed mode for Samsung Galaxy Note. 
Is there such an ability for Windows Phone 8.1 (Nokia Lumia 1520)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few accessibility features on Windows Phone you can find in your settings, but none that specifically help you operate large screen phones. 
You might want to check out http://windowsphone.uservoice.com and add this as a suggestion.

EDIT: Microsoft announced that [there will be a feature in Windows 10 Mobile](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-one-handed-split-screen-feature) just like in iOS. It is already part of the latest preview build and works on all devices with 5" screens or larger.

Comment: https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5963711-one-handed-operation for Samsung's one handed operation mode and https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6993315-please-add-something-like-reachability-on-iphone6 for iOS's Reachability